# PHP Maximum File Upload Configuration Problems

Tags: php

I've met some confusing problems about how php.ini post_max_size, and upload_max_filesize works. Reading the php.net documentation, i know that by setting post_max_size = 16M and upload_max_filesize = 16M, will make us able to upload maximum of 16MB file. But what i've seen it's not. I'm checking the loaded .ini value using this

```
$max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
$max_post = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
$memory_limit = (int)(ini_get('memory_limit'));
$upload_mb = min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);

echo $max_upload;
echo $max_post;
echo $memory_limit;
echo $upload_mb;
```

The Output:

```
2
8
96
2
```

The value is not the same as what i've specified in this php.ini!

Here's my php.ini config: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2o1vMJ7XFKyT0xDWUhJTnR0M2c/edit?usp=sharing

I've already make sure that this config is the one that php interpreter loaded, by checking the output of phpinfo();

Thanks

Comment: There might be php_admin_value for entire web hosting (if you use it) it overrides any values that might be set in user scripts or .htaccess files

Comment: Did you restart or reload web server to pick up new php config?

Comment: Yes I did..
I'm really confused. If anyone interested, i can upload my VM. It's Virtualbox VDI Image

Comment: What does phpinfo() output for those values?

Comment: Also, are you using a simple, single .php file to test this? If you're using a framework it's possible it could be overriding your values with calls to `ini_set`.

Comment: I'm using pure php script

Here's phpinfo output. Please download it first from google drive, and open it from the browser 

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2o1vMJ7XFKydk9nNnV1bW5QcFE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To share output with others it's easier to use codepad or pastebin instead of google docs.

Comment: If you're using fpm, you must restart it when making config changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the solution to my own problem.
By checking /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini more thorough, I've found out that:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED ~E_DEPRECATED
```

By fixing that value into

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Fixes the problem. 
And the reason why i had those nested value in the first place is because, i'm using sed to modify the value in the first place, and i forgot to escape '&' character. (& means insert substring, so it will insert the string before that). After escaping it into '\&', the sed command works as expected.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

are You sure change correct php.ini see the  Apache config for php ini directory maybe you change another php.ini

search for something like this in  Apache config that is for set php ini directory

```
 PHPINIDir "c:/php"
```

the another  problem maybe accord   is set this parameters  in htaccess,if set the  parameters  overwrite in run.

like

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
 php_value post_max_size 10M
```

notice: htaccess sometimes set in parent directory

Comment: Yes, i'm sure this is the correct php.ini loaded. From phpinof() output : 
`<tr><td class="e">Loaded Configuration File </td><td class="v">/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini </td></tr>`

That is the php.ini config that i uploaded in my question above

Comment: yes you are right, check Apache ,Apache  can set php_value

Comment: I'm using Nginx, not Apache

Comment: ok no problem check Nginx config web server can set php_value